# How to get comma-separated values in excel?

Tags: excel, csv, excel-2007

I have a value in a cell like this: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

and in another cell like `2,4,5,9`

I want a result like `1,3,6,7,8,10` in the desired cell.

Comment: The content does not reflect your initial title question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be willing to create your own Function?

I think what your trying to say is that you want to display the Unique Values from Cell 1 that are not found in the "other" cell...

Basically my function will loop through the first cell by splitting it by the "," Comma delimiter and assign each value to a Dictionary Object.  Then it will go through the second cell in same fashion but if that value exists within the Dictionary Object, it removes it... leaving only the Unique Items which it then joins the array with the comma delimiter...

Place the below code into a Module and reference it in the cell by

> =GetUnique(A1, A2)

```
Public Function GetUnique(RangeA As Range, RangeB As Range)
Dim objDic As Object
Dim X As Variant

Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each X In Split(RangeA.Value, ",")
    If Not objDic.exists(X) Then
        objDic.Add X, objDic.Count
    End If
Next
For Each X In Split(RangeB.Value, ",")
    If objDic.exists(X) Then
        objDic.Remove (X)
    End If
Next
GetUnique = Join(objDic.keys, ",")
End Function
```

Comment: @B Hart thanks for reply.how to create module.i am new to this.

Comment: @VivekParikh easiest way from Excel is to press Alt + F11 Keys to open the Microsoft Visual Basic Editor.  Right Click within your VBA Project and select Insert Module...  Select the Module (will be blank) and copy past this code into it...  You will now be able to reference the homemade function within an Excel cell.  There should be tons of tutorials on Google, StackOverflow, and even YouTube if you need more help :)